# DXL code to export OLE object to Excel and specify “Placement” parameter

Tags: excel, ibm-doors

I've tried to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40028654/wanted-dxl-code-to-export-ole-object-to-excel-and-specify-placement-parameter), but the last section is giving me some issues- DOORS is giving an error "incorrect arguments for function (excelShapeRangePlacement)".

Can anyone share the working DXL file or the excelSizeShape subroutine, please?

Answer (score 1):

so it's hard to pinpoint the exact issue without full context of the DXL runtime error you're getting from DOORS. What that answer is attempting to implement I think is this Excel VBA shape property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.placement

But from looking at the linked question/answer, you need to make sure certain parameters are met before this solution will work.

1. Ensure all 3 pieces of code in the answer are found somewhere in your code:

   const string cExcelPropertyPlacement = "Placement"

   void excelShapeRangePlacement( OleAutoObj objExcelShapeRange, int OlePlacement ) {
   olePut(objExcelShapeRange, cExcelPropertyPlacement, OlePlacement)
   }

   excelShapeRangePlacement(objExcelShapeRange, 1)
2. Before excelShapeRangePlacement() can be successfully run, you need to write code to set the OleAutoObj objExcelShapeRange variable to that shape object. This part may be difficult if you have never done any VBA. In the GalaticSolutions link in the original post, it contains some code for this, but I'm not sure if the OLEs in your script are setup the same way where you will be able to use their code. If you open up their code, see function excelSizeShape().

Hope that helps! Good luck!